# jsonkit user defined issues and arc restrictions on trying to import it from objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jsonkit

So it's my first time to try and use jsonkit. I've been looking for the past hour and couldn't find any installation instructions so I just tried copying and pasting the files and then adding them into the xcode project and then import them. But when I compile it would throw a dozen errors, which would usually have ARC restrictions on it. One of these errors has this :

> JSONKit does not support Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting

With that said, are there any specific instructions I need to follow for this to compile properly? Or maybe point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Happening because here you are mixing the non-arc Code in ARC Code,that's why this error is coming.You can use below idea of mine and it works fine , have used the same in past
.

Hey You can Disable `ARC` for `JSON classes` by just set a `flag` in under the `Build Phases` of `App setting`.

and the flag is

```
 -fno-objc-arc
```

As Below Image depicts the Way how to do this.

[image: See The Below Image...!!! carefully]

It would work with charm..!!!!